# Unity's Google In-App Review plugin error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.play.core.review.ReviewManagerFactory

Tags: unity-game-engine, android-unity-plugin

I'm trying to integrate Google's [In-app Review](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review/unity) feature into my Unity application and getting the following runtime error message on logcat console. Anyone knows the solution to this problem?

`AndroidJavaException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.play.core.review.ReviewManagerFactory  (Filename: currently not available on il2cpp Line: -1)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It turned out that the problem was introduced by a proguard obfuscation. In order to keep the symbols I had to add the following to the proguard definition file:

`-keep class com.google.android.play.core.** { *; }`

Comment: I am using Gradle for my minification.  Any ideas on a solution there?

Comment: I'm using _minifyEnabled_ as well. Try first setting it up to _false_ to check if minification process is the culprit in your case

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that has this issue. For me, I had to force resolve Android external dependencies

Comment: Can you leave a bit of details on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Like Eric said in the response, it isn't Proguard that is causing it

It is the Minify.  Disable that crap.  Not only does Minify ruins your android core library, but possible other assets as well, including Mirror Network.  There is no workaround it.

Trust me.  I spent all day debugging it for you all thoroughly so you wouldn't have to:   **Just disable Minify and keep Proguard**.

By disabling minify, which doesn't do much for you anyways, you WOULD NOT need to include this line in your Proguard file:

```
-keep class com.google.android.play.core.** { *; }
```

You can just leave this out, keep the proguard setting to its default and it'll work perfectly